# Система лайков

Tags: веб-программирование, php, memcached, javascript, база-данных

Привет, есть задача: реализовать систему лайков. Пользователь, может ставить лайк другому пользователю, и причем только один. Имеется сайт, с 25тыс+ пользователей. Посещаемость 6-7 тыс уников в сутки. При авторизации пользователь кешируется в мемкеше и все данные его данные берутся оттуда. Есть идея, при авторизации кешировать те лайки, которые ставил пользователь, чтоб не лезть лишний раз в базу. Или же делать в лоб, таблица с двумя полями (id пользователя, который ставит лайк и id того, кто его получает). Собственно хотелось бы увидеть ваши мнения по этому поводу, интересные и красивые решения.

Comment: Может просто лимит лайков и не важно кого конкретно пользователь лайкал? Базу использовать только тогда, когда нужно узнать кого конкретно пользователь лайкал.

Comment: Как Вами и сказано - таблица с двумя полями. Только в добавок первичный ключ по этим ДВУМ ПОЛЯМ.

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать VIEW для этих лайков. Как раз будет 2 поля и никаких первичных ключей. Через пару-тройку десятков запросов БД будет работать быстрее.

Очень важно базе данных иметь хороший диск. При работе с Magento испытал радость перехода с обычного физического диска на SSD)

Answer (score 1):

Запрос по [кластерному ключу](http://habrahabr.ru/post/141767/) (а он будет такой) работает очень-очень быстро :).

Очевидно запись в лайки происходит намного реже, чем чтение. Значит сервер БД будет *эффективно кешировать* данные самостоятельно. Надо только дать ему достаточно памяти и выставить параметры конфигурации.

Не факт, что отдавая часть ресурсов конкретно под кеш лайков вы  выигрываете в общей производительности. Оптимизация это проблема приоритетов.

Comment: Похоже вы опоздали на два года)

Comment: Вы правы ))) Почему-то этот вопрос появился в ленте. Мне даже в голову не пришло смотреть его дату.